# html5 type="number" working so slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when we change input value, i will throw the value into console.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#a, #b').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="a" value="1">
<input type="text" id="b" value="1">
```

**try**: step/press up type=number several times.

**result**: browser hang for a while (more than 1 sec) for type=number , but for type=text it happened instantly

**expected**: the elapsed times is same. even for miliseconds (under 1 sec) is fine.

the possible reason is type=number verify/parse the input first, so that's why it took more times. But why it takes so long, even hang up my browser??

Comment: The change event waits for the user to finish changing the value before triggering. Use `.on('input')` if you want the event to trigger immediately whenever the value changes.

Comment: i did the same and didn't faced any issue..seems like your browser is loaded with plugins or something

Comment: It does happen to me. I click the up arrow many times, then Chrome hangs for more than one second, then finally displays the value (only the current value, not all intermediates one by one). That's very weird indeed

Comment: Also, not very accurate to say that the browser "hangs". It doesn't hang, it's just waiting for the user to finish. If it really hangs (i.e. stops responding to any input) then that's a different matter.

Comment: The code performs as it should, the number input is working fine, the text input waits for onfocus out before it fires the change event.

Comment: It seems to trigger after the `blur` of field and `mouseout/enter` on the arrows. This seems like correct behaviour of the change event to me. This is actually a good thing, it's nice to have slow repeating events so you don't have to debounce it yourself.

Comment: @René  im agree with you. i just shocked when i know this today. `JJJ` thanks, your hack works better than i did before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the issue with `.on()` and with `input` trigger as per below. Seems `change()` is not triggering well for input `type=number` up and down buttons.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#a, #b').on("input",function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="a" value="1">
<input type="text" id="b" value="1">
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that `change` doesn't work well. It feels like it's debounced or something, because in the end it _does_ log the current value

Comment: @JeremyThille Yeah. agree it is not doing well when we click. But working fine with up and down arrow on the keyboard.

Comment: i'm agree with you all. I'll check this because this method seems more faster than my example